# disambiguation of "quite": completely or not completely?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

According to my dictionary (Cambridge Advanced Learner's), the two most frequent meanings of the word "quite" are surprisingly opposing:

1. *a little or a lot but not completely*
2. *completely*

Although there is a row of examples for each of the meanings, in my understanding the following sample sentences would match both of the meanings above:

> The two situations are quite different.
>
> You've made your position quite clear.
>
> She seemed quite chirpy this morning.
>
> It would be quite a nuisance to write to everyone.
>
> It was quite a difficult job.
>
> She was quite affable at the meeting.
>
> There's quite a collection of toothbrushes in the bathroom.

How can I resp. how would you decide which meaning is meant for each of the following sentences?

Comment: **quite** means "to a considerable degree" or "to a significant degree" and it can mean "almost completely".  It never means "completely".

Comment: I've never known [*quite*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quite) to mean *a little*, so I'm surprised by that first definition you provided.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo It depends on context: *I am* ***quite*** *finished*. In that sentence, it *is* synonymous with *completely*. (Look at the first sense of the word in the Merriam-Webster link in my previous comment.)

Comment: I think **finished** there carries the sense of "completely" and **quite** is just an intensifier.

Answer (score 3):

***Quite*** can in fact mean *a little bit* or *slightly*, or it can mean *very*, or it can mean *completely*.

In any given phrase or sentence, it could mean either. There's some rules of thumb that might help, but usually you have to work it out from context.

For example, if it is used with an ostensibly absolute adjective, like *dead*, *empty* or *exhausted*, it usually means *completely*.

> There's no chance of us finding out what he saw, I'm afraid. He's **quite** dead.

If it is doubled, usually either side of a comma, it usually means *completely*.

> I'm **quite, quite** sure.

The special case of ***not quite*** means *almost*, which is a case of it meaning *completely* as well.

> Wait, I'm **not quite** finished!

I can't think of any rules of thumb to be sure it is being used to mean *very* or *slightly*. If it's not clearly *completely*, then it might be *very* or *slightly*, and you have to judge from context, and from tone if it is spoken.

Answer (score -1):

> **Quite**

Usually has the meaning of

> to the utmost or most absolute extent or degree

Synonyms are

> completely
>   fully
>   entirely
>   totally
>   wholly

In your example sentences

> The two situations are **quite** different.
>   *The two situations are* ***very*** *different.*
>
> You've made your position **quite** clear.
>   *You've made your position* ***completely*** *clear*.